# ng-file-upload - Android does not allow user to select local file

Tags: android, angularjs, ng-file-upload

Using ng-file-upload and like the plugin but for Android's it is not working. Using Galaxy S6 and chrome and when user goes to take a picture Android goes right to the camera without giving them any options. This does not happen on iOS and the user is prompted to either use the camera or other options.

Is there another config setting that needs to be added or changed for Android to give the user options:

Example of the implementation I am using:

```
<div ng-form="fileUploadForm" name="fileUploadForm">

<div ng-hide="model"
     ngf-select="fileSelected()"
     ngf-fix-orientation="true"
     ngf-capture="'camera'"
     ngf-accept="'image/*'"
     ngf-validate-fn="validate($file)"
     ngf-keep="true"
     class="file-upload show-errors">
  Image
</div>

<div ng-show="model">
  <img ngf-src="model"
       ngf-resize="{ratio: '1.4:1', quality: 0.9}"
       class="uploaded-image"/>
  <div>
    <a ngf-select="fileSelected()"
       ngf-fix-orientation="true"
       ngf-capture="'camera'"
       ngf-accept="'image/*'"
       ngf-validate-fn="validate($file)"
       ngf-keep="true">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does the `ngf-capture="'camera'"` need to be set to `other` to allow for user to have options on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like having this `ngf-capture="'camera'"` was the culprit. Apparently it makes Android only use the camera but iOS will use either the camera or local storage when it is there.